# Puppet agent is not running successfully after updating ssl certs

Tags: ssl, puppet

I am running puppet 3.7. The certs are expiring for me so I have updated the certs (after creating a backup so I am able to get back to the original state and that's fine). After updating the certs on puppetmaster using [this](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3.7/ssl_regenerate_certificates.html#step-1-clear-and-regenerate-certs-on-your-puppet-master), updating certs on the agent using [this](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3.7/ssl_regenerate_certificates.html#step-3-clear-and-regenerate-certs-for-puppet-agents) and updating certs on puppetdb using [this](https://docs.puppet.com/puppetdb/1.4/install_from_source.html#step-3-option-b-manually-generating-and-preparing-certificates), I am unable to run puppet agent successfully on a client box. It gives me the following error:

`root@ip-10-181-36:/var/lib/puppet# sudo puppet agent -t
Warning: Setting templatedir is deprecated. See http://links.puppetlabs.com/env-settings-deprecations
   (at /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/settings.rb:1139:in 'issue_deprecation_warning')
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: Error 403 on SERVER: Forbidden request: newer-generic-host(127.0.0.1) access to /node/ip-10-181-36 [find] authenticated  at :39
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 403 on SERVER: Forbidden request: newer-generic-host(127.0.0.1) access to /catalog/ip-10-181-36 [find] authenticated  at :1
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: Error 403 on SERVER: Forbidden request: newer-generic-host(127.0.0.1) access to /report/ip-10-181-36 [save] authenticated  at :91`

I am stuck at this point and no googling or reading docs or seeing the logs is helping. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you running puppetserver? Is there anything regarding this in the master's logs?